# Hoisting expressions with module.exports on top

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, hoisting

While studying the node.js library, I observed that `util.inherits(Stream, EE);`
  is called **after** the expression `module.exports = Stream`.

```
module.exports = Stream;

const EE = require('events');
const util = require('util');

util.inherits(Stream, EE);

function Stream() {
  EE.call(this);
}
```

`util.inherits` is a function call (and from my understanding, not hoisted), and so my question is, how is it that we can continue modifying the exported object after the expression?

I have noticed other examples of modules that are first exported and then (later in the code) appended with additional prototypes in the form of expressions. How is it that works when something like the following doesn't?

```
module.exports = {
  func1: doSomething,
};

var doSomething = function() {
  console.log("Hello World");
};
```

Comment: You can change the object reference, but you cannot replace it with another object reference or value. As far as your last example, that doesn't work because you hoisted an undefined value, passed undefined into the object, and then re-defined the value as something else later.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!